# How can I have a page showing reservations update when a customer adds a reservation from another computer (using Rails)?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I would like to have a page where a restaurant can log in and see all of their current reservations/take-out orders, and I want this page to automatically update when someone (from another computer) makes a reservation or places an order. The idea is that the restaurant would leave this page open at all times to show their current status. What is the best way to do this? Can it be done without refreshing the page?

I wasn't even sure how to refer to a setup like this, so I wasn't really able to find much using Google. Is there a word for this type of setup?

I am using rails, and I am considering using AngularJS for the front end. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches to solving this.

The first, oldest, simplest is that your webpage contains some javascript that will poll the server at regular intervals (e.g. every 10-30 seconds), to check if something has changed and then add the changed data (e.g. reload a partial).

The second approach is a bit cleaner, and it allows the server to push the changed data to the connected clients, only when it is changed.

There are a few available approaches/libraries for this:

- use websockets
- use [pusher](http://pusher.com)
- use <del>juggernaut</del> The author of juggernaut had deprecated it, in favor of using HTLM5 SSE (server sent events). [Read more](http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/killing-a-library).

The advantage of using polling is that it is easy, works on every browser, but you have to write more code yourself, you will put some kind of load on your server, even if data has not changed (although the load is minimal).

The push-technologies are newer, work very clean, less code is needed. But some work only in newer browser (most of the times not really an issue), and some require extra support/setting up on your server-side.

On that note: pusher is really easy to get started with, and if your load is limited, it is free.

There are still a lot of others, but this should get you started in the right direction.